# View the contents of a database joined together and separated by a hyphen in combobox

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

How can i display the contents of the same line in a combobox (in the City1 and City2 field) combined with a dash to form a travel destination?

For example i would like to display in the combobox: London-Manchester and then Paris-Bordeaux (both destinations, so two items in the combobox).

In the code there is my attempt to solve it, but as you can see it is wrong, very wrong, you can already see it by eye. I am new to Python

```
CREATE TABLE "destinations" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "city1" INTEGER, #London, #Paris
    "city2" INTEGER, #Manchester, #Bordeaux
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

1, London, Manchester
2, Paris, Bordeaux
```

Tkinter window:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

app=Tk()
app.title(" ")
app.geometry("300x200")

con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

combo=ttk.Combobox(app, width=21)
combo.place(x=30, y=20)
combo.config(values=combo)
combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>')
combo.set("Select")
combos=["destinations"]

city1= cursor.execute "SELECT city1 FROM destinations"
city2= cursor.execute "SELECT city1 FROM destinations"

destinations = "city1" "-" "city2"

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issue you came across?

Comment: @DavidTorres0101 you need to have had a genuine attempt at figuring out your own question before asking here. See [ask]

Comment: Either you combine the two fields using SQLite `concatenate operator ||` in the SQL statement, or using Python string function `.join()`.

Comment: @jezza_99 I apologize. I'm new to this site and just starting out with Python. I edited the question and showed my attempt which of course it was

Comment: @acw1668 I thank you for the answer. Theoretically I understand, but in practice maybe not. I am new to Python. Could you show me your code idea in an answer please? I also edited the question, adding the attempt as I had tried earlier, but of course it was wrong .Thanks

Comment: Should `city1` and `city2` be of type `TEXT` in the CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: @acw1668 text. I can't rate your answer. I get "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.". I am very sorry. I signed up only yesterday . I will vote for it after the next question. I will not forget. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two fields by either

- using SQLite `concatenate operator ||`

```py
cursor.execute('SELECT city1 || "-" || city2 FROM destinations')
values = [row[0] for row in cursor]
```

- or using Python string `.join()`

```py
cursor.execute('SELECT city1, city2 FROM destinations')
values = ['-'.join(row) for row in cursor]
```

Then assign the result to `values` option of `Combobox`:

```py
combo.config(values=values)
```

---

Full example code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('300x200')

cnx = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT city1 || "-" || city2 FROM destinations')
values = [row[0] for row in cursor]
'''
cursor.execute('SELECT city1, city2 FROM destinations')
values = ['-'.join(row) for row in cursor]
'''
print(values)

combo = ttk.Combobox(app, width=21, values=values, state='readonly')
combo.place(x=30, y=20)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: And to have it displayed in the combobox? Is it enough just combo.config (values = values) or do I have to write something else? For example I had written combos = ["destinations"]. Thanks

Comment: @DavidTorres0101 Added example code.

Comment: I thank you. You have been very kind. I'll test it tomorrow and vote for your answer, because it's late now and I have to go to sleep. Thanks. I'll answer tomorrow

Comment: @  Could you help me with this question please? I'm new and I didn't have enough score yesterday to rate your answer. If you help me with this question, I will vote on your answer, so increase reputation and vote on your other answer (i.e. this one). Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998707/calculate-arithmetic-mean-based-on-database-fields-directly-from-python-not-w

Comment: Could you help me with this question please? I'm new and I didn't have enough score yesterday to rate your answer. If you help me with this question, I will vote on your answer, so increase reputation and vote on your other answer (i.e. this one). Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998707/calculate-arithmetic-mean-based-on-database-fields-directly-from-python-not-w

Comment: Thank you, but now i riceve this error: mean_candy_launched = sum(int(row[0]) for row in rows) / len(rows) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'