# Calculate arithmetic mean based on database fields? (directly from Python, not with sql)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple arithmetic mean calculator. It will calculate the average of the candies thrown and received. So how many candies player1 on the left threw into player2's box on the right and how many he received.

To do this I will use a combobox where I can select the name of the player (to whom I have given the names of the colors). For example by selecting "Yellow-Black" or "Red-Green", I would like to calculate the arithmetic average for the Yellow player and for the Red player based on the previous matches saved in the database.

[image]

For example in this case I would have to add 2 + 1 + 2 (box_left only for Candy_launched) and then divide them by 3. Same thing for Yellow.

I get the error: `TypeError: mean_candy_received () missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Candy_received_Box_left' and 'number_clashes'`

I'll probably have some other simple thing wrong too. I'm just starting out with Python. For example in number_clashes I can't make only Candy_launched count in box_left (for example for Red they are 2 + 1 + 2). Can you help me please?

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE "clashes" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "day"   INTEGER,
    "box_left"  INTEGER,
    "box_right" INTEGER,
    "Candy_launched"    INTEGER,
    "Candy_received"    INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
```

Tkinter:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    import tkinter as tk
    import sqlite3
    
    app=Tk()
    app.title(" ")
    app.geometry("300x400")
    
    #####################################
    #DATABASE
    con = sqlite3.connect('/database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    
    #Set candy values
    #Box Left
    Candy_launched_Box_left = cursor.execute('SELECT Candy_launched FROM clashes')
    Candy_received_Box_left = cursor.execute('SELECT Candy_received FROM clashes')
    
    #Count Number clashes
    number_clashes = cursor.execute("SELECT day FROM clashes ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")
    
   #####################################

    #Function Arithmetic mean  
    def mean_candy_launched(Candy_launched_Box_left, number_clashes):
        return float(sum(Candy_launched_Box_left)) / (number_clashes.count), 1
    
    def mean_candy_received(Candy_received_Box_left, number_clashes):
        return float(sum(Candy_received_Box_left)) / (number_clashes.count), 1
    
    def other_changed():
        null
    
    ##################################
    #GUI
    
    #Combobox Clashes
    cursor.execute('SELECT box_left || "-" || box_right FROM clashes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2')
    values = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    
    
    combo = ttk.Combobox(app, width=21, values=values)
    combo.set("Select Clashes")
    combo.place(x=20, y=20)
    
    
    #View Results
    BoxLeft = Label(app, text="BOX LEFT", foreground='black',  font='arial 12 bold')
    BoxLeft.place(x=30, y=130)
    
    Mean_Candy_launched = Label(app, text="Mean Candy launched:", foreground='black',  font='arial 11')
    Mean_Candy_launched.place(x=30, y=160)
    Mean_Candy_received = Label(app, text="Mean Candy received:", foreground='black',  font='arial 11')
    Mean_Candy_received.place(x=30, y=190)
    
    Result_Mean_Candy_launched = Label(app, text=" ? ", foreground='black',  font='arial 11')
    Result_Mean_Candy_launched.place(x=190, y=160)
    
    Result_Mean_Candy_received = Label(app, text=" ? ", foreground='black',  font='arial 11')
    Result_Mean_Candy_received.place(x=190, y=190)
    
    
    Result_Mean_Candy_launched = mean_candy_launched
    Result_Mean_Candy_received = mean_candy_received
    
    
    #Button
    button = Button(app, text="Calculate", command = mean_candy_launched and mean_candy_received)
    button.pack()
    button.place(x=30, y=260)
    
    
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: your mean candy launched function and mean candy recieved function expect some arguments ... you are not sending any ... and i dont think that command does what you would expect...

Comment: @JoranBeasley In fact, I had noticed that that could be the problem. I am new to Python. They are at the beginning. Can you help me show the code please? Thank you

Comment: I would recommend you to go through few tutorials for beginner on Python and SQL before proceeding.  After having basic knowledge on Python and SQL, you can solve the question on your own.

Comment: @acw1668 I am studying from W3School and on other sites. A little study and a little write codes. I believe my question is simple. If you help me, your help will be very useful for study purposes. I will study your answer if you are kind enough to answer me. Stackoverflow exists to answer even young beginner questions. In case you don't want to help me, thanks anyway

Comment: @acw1668 P.S: I got a few more points of reputation and I voted your answer of the other question

Comment: Basically you need only one SQL to get the required values: `cursor.execute('SELECT AVG(Candy_launched), AVG(Candy_received) FROM clashes WHERE box_left = ?', [box_left])` where `box_left` is extracted from the selected item of `combo`.

Comment: @acw1668 I see. Thanks. For example I am studying SQL, but I hadn't seen AVG yet. Here, your comment has educational value for me and I will study your answer. What's wrong with the mean_candy_launched function (to calculate the arithmetic mean)? Could you help me? Thanks. I appreciate it so much. Meanwhile, I also study, but these answers of yours are very useful for me and for the stackoverflow community.

Comment: @acw1668 I read that AVG is used to calculate the average itself via SQL. I wanted to calculate the average through Python, not through Sql. I wrote it in the title of the question

Answer (score 0):

`command = mean_candy_launched and mean_candy_received` will not execute both `mean_candy_launched()` and `mean_candy_received()` as you expect.

`mean_candy_launched and mean_candy_received` will return reference to `mean_candy_received()`, so `command` option will be assigned the reference of `mean_candy_received()`.  However callback for `command` option expects no argument, but your function definition expect two arguments.  That's why the exception raised.

You just need a callback to calculate the two means together inside it:

```py
def calc_means():
    selected = combo.get()
    if selected:
        box_left = selected.split('-')[0]
        '''
        # using SQL to calculate the means
        cursor.execute('SELECT AVG(Candy_launched), AVG(Candy_received) FROM clashes WHERE box_left = ?', [box_left])
        mean_candy_launched, mean_candy_received = cursor.fetchone()
        '''
        cursor.execute('SELECT Candy_launched, Candy_received FROM clashes WHERE box_left = ?', [box_left])
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        if rows:
            mean_candy_launched = sum(row[0] for row in rows) / len(rows)
            mean_candy_received = sum(row[1] for row in rows) / len(rows)
            # update results
            Result_Mean_Candy_launched['text'] = round(mean_candy_launched, 2)
            Result_Mean_Candy_received['text'] = round(mean_candy_received, 2)
```

Then assign this function to `command` option of <kbd>Calculate</kbd> button:

```py
button = Button(app, text='Calculate', command=calc_means)
```

Modified example code based on yours:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

def calc_means():
    selected = combo.get()
    if selected:
        box_left = selected.split('-')[0]
        '''
        # using SQL to calculate the means
        cursor.execute('SELECT AVG(Candy_launched), AVG(Candy_received) FROM clashes WHERE box_left = ?', [box_left])
        mean_candy_launched, mean_candy_received = cursor.fetchone()
        '''
        cursor.execute('SELECT Candy_launched, Candy_received FROM clashes WHERE box_left = ?', [box_left])
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        if rows:
            mean_candy_launched = sum(row[0] for row in rows) / len(rows)
            mean_candy_received = sum(row[1] for row in rows) / len(rows)
            # update results
            Result_Mean_Candy_launched['text'] = round(mean_candy_launched, 2)
            Result_Mean_Candy_received['text'] = round(mean_candy_received, 2)

cnx = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('300x400')

cursor.execute('SELECT box_left||"-"||box_right FROM clashes LIMIT 2')
values = [row[0] for row in cursor]

combo = ttk.Combobox(app, width=21, values=values, state='readonly')
combo.place(x=20, y=20)

tk.Label(app, text='BOX LEFT', font='arial 12 bold').place(x=30, y=130)
tk.Label(app, text='Mean Candy launched:', font='arial 11').place(x=30, y=160)
tk.Label(app, text='Mean Candy received:', font='arial 11').place(x=30, y=190)

Result_Mean_Candy_launched = tk.Label(app, text='?', font='arial 11')
Result_Mean_Candy_launched.place(x=190, y=160)

Result_Mean_Candy_received = tk.Label(app, text='?', font='arial 11')
Result_Mean_Candy_received.place(x=190, y=190)

tk.Button(app, text='Calculate', command=calc_means).place(x=30, y=260)

app.mainloop()
```

Note that I have removed `from tkinter import *` as wildcard import is not recommended.

---

*Update*: as fields `Candy_launched` and `Candy_received` are strings and can be empty based on the comment, it is required to filter out those records with the two fields being empty:

```py
def calc_means():
    selected = combo.get()
    if selected:
        box_left = selected.split('-')[0]
        cursor.execute('''
            SELECT Candy_launched, Candy_received FROM clashes
            WHERE box_left = ?
              AND TRIM(Candy_launched) != ''
              AND TRIM(Candy_received) != ''
        ''', [box_left])
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        if rows:
            mean_candy_launched = sum(int(row[0]) for row in rows) / len(rows)
            mean_candy_received = sum(int(row[1]) for row in rows) / len(rows)
            # update results
            Result_Mean_Candy_launched['text'] = round(mean_candy_launched, 2)
            Result_Mean_Candy_received['text'] = round(mean_candy_received, 2)
```

Comment: You are really very kind. Yours is a great answer, useful to both me and stackoverflow readers. I will study your answer as if it were a book. I'll read your answer better tonight, because now I'm going to sleep which is very late. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanking you again for your kindness, I get an error from your code. I get: mean_candy_launched = sum (row [0] for row in rows) / len (rows) TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. I get this error when I click the button after selecting in the combobox. How to solve? Thanks

Comment: I don't have such issue.  You need to check the type of `row[0]` which is expected to be integer.  If it is a string (although it shouldn't be), then try `sum(int(row[0]) for row in rows)`.

Comment: How come you don't have this problem? Did you use a database similar to mine to write the code? If you look above in my question there is the database I used

Comment: Using sum (int (row [0]) for row in rows), I get the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10: ''. However the line type is integer, so I don't understand the previous TypeError error: type (s) operand not supported for +: 'int' and 'str'. There is something wrong

Comment: Then there are records with empty string.  Use `sum(int(row[0]) for row in rows if row[0].strip() != "")`.  I have created a sample table for testing, but the type of the two fields are integers and without records with empty values.

Comment: I am confused why `row[0]` sometimes is a string and sometimes it is integer in your table.

Comment: Yes, those empty records I left voluntarily. They serve only as an example to visualize the next two candy fights inside the combobox. So those two blank records don't have to be considered.

Comment: Could you help me please? Thank you

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10: '-'. I remembered commenting a few days ago, I will remember badly, sorry.

Comment: You can modify the SQL to suit your situation.  It is not hard if you have basic knowledge on SQL.  It is better to go through some tutorials on Python and SQL than just copy and paste other's code without understanding.